# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded using Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

While setting up `Stanford CoreNLP`, I am running into following exception since a long time:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:407)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3388)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:3183)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(ObjectInputStream.java:1863)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1526)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1402)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readObjectFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:310)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.statistical.FeatureExtractor.loadVocabulary(FeatureExtractor.java:90)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.statistical.FeatureExtractor.<init>(FeatureExtractor.java:75)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.statistical.StatisticalCorefAlgorithm.<init>(StatisticalCorefAlgorithm.java:63)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.statistical.StatisticalCorefAlgorithm.<init>(StatisticalCorefAlgorithm.java:44)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.CorefAlgorithm.fromProps(CorefAlgorithm.java:30)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.CorefSystem.<init>(CorefSystem.java:40)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.CorefAnnotator.<init>(CorefAnnotator.java:69)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.coref(AnnotatorImplementations.java:218)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$17(StanfordCoreNLP.java:641)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$$Lambda$27/1579572132.apply(Unknown Source)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$null$33(StanfordCoreNLP.java:711)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$$Lambda$40/2104457164.get(Unknown Source)
```

System Details:

```
MacOS
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Command for which the exception occurs:

```
java edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -file input.txt
```

I think I also have setup the right `CLASSPATH`. See the result for `echo $CLASSPATH`

```
:/Users/krishna/Downloads/NLP/stanford-corenlp-4.5.1/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed using the flag `-Xms3056m` which increases the default memory to `3GB` to be used by `CoreNLP`.

```
java -Xms3056m -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -file input.txt
```